# Python SWIG wrapper for C++ rvalue std::string &&

Tags: python, c++11, swig, gnucash

I'm trying to build a python wrapper for gnucash c++ parts. In [QofBackend](https://code.gnucash.org/docs/MASTER/structQofBackend.html) I encountered the method `const std::string && get_message ()`. In python this message returns `<Swig Object of type 'std::string *' at 0x7f4a20f5c9f0>` instead of a string as in my setting as there is no swig typemap for std::string rvalue reference.

I didn't really find a simple explanation so I rebuilt an example setting and dug into c++ which I barely know. I managed to get the string into python but I'd like to know

- if this typemap(out) approach is correct (also in respect of memory and error handling).
- The conversion in `set_s_workaround()` is also just a workaround. I don't think that for gnucash the python code ever needs to set this value but for completeness sake it would be nice to also have a `typemap(in) std::string&&` and
- get rid of `get_s_workaround`
- get init_s_2 working.

```cpp
/* example.hpp */
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct struct1{
        string s;
        const std::string&& get_s();
        void set_s(string&&);
        void set_s_workaround(string);
        void init_s();
        void init_s_2();
        void print_s();
};

string conv_rvalue_string(string);
```

```cpp
/* example.cpp */
#include<iostream> 
#include"example.hpp"

using namespace std; 

void
struct1::set_s (std::string&& msg)
{
     s = msg;
}

std::string
conv_rvalue_string (std::string msg)
{
        return msg;
}

void
struct1::set_s_workaround(std::string msg)
{
        set_s ( conv_rvalue_string(msg) );
}

void
struct1::init_s ()
{
     set_s("Some content");
}

void
struct1::init_s_2()
{
     std::string msg {"Couldn't find "};
     /* set_s( msg ); */
}

void
struct1::print_s ()
{
     cout<<get_s()<<endl;
}

const std::string&&
struct1::get_s ()
{
    return std::move(s);
}
```

```
/* example.i */
%module example

%include "std_string.i"

%typemap(out) std::string&& {
  std::string s = *$1;
  $result = SWIG_From_std_string(s);
}


%{
#include <string>
#include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "example.hpp"
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
swig3.0 -c++ -shadow -python example.i
g++ -fpic -c example.hpp example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.7
g++ -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o _example.so
```

```py
# pyexample.py
import example

s1 = example.struct1()
s1.set_s_workaround('TEST')
s1.print_s()
print(s1.get_s())
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `std::string &&` typemap uses a temporary `std::string` that is passed to the method that takes a `std::string` rvalue reference.
The fragment dependecies in the `%typemap` ensure that the used fragments are ready in the wrapper file. We simply use the fragments that are already provided by `"std_string.i"`.

```
/* example.i */
%module example

%include "std_string.i"

%typemap(out, fragment="SWIG_From_std_string") std::string&& {
  $result = SWIG_From_std_string(*$1);
}

%typemap(in, fragment="SWIG_AsVal_std_string") std::string&& (std::string temp) {
  int res = SWIG_AsVal_std_string($input, &temp);
  $1 = &temp;
}

%{
#include <string>
#include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "example.hpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

init_s2() would work like this:

```
void
struct1::init_s_2()
{
     std::string msg {"Couldn't find "};
     set_s( msg + "");
}
```

credits to S. Holtermann!

```
%typemap(out) std::string&& {
  std::string s = *$1;
  $result = SWIG_From_std_string(s);
}
```

can be shortened to

```
%typemap(out) std::string&& {
  $result = SWIG_From_std_string(*$1);
}
```

without creating a local var (credits to S. Holtermann!)

A possible typemap(in) could be

```
%typemap(in) std::string && (std::string *temp){
   int res = SWIG_AsPtr_std_string($input, &temp);
   $1 = temp;
}
```

- works
- hasn't been tested extensively
- does it cause memory leaks?

Comment: This leaks the allocated temp string.